# What's the meaning of subtracting 'a' from elements of char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

1. What's the meaning of `a[s1[i] - 'a']` and
2. `int a[26] = {0}` (I'm not sure but is it for initializing every element of a array to 0 value)

```
int main()
{
    char s1[10010], s2[10010];
    cin >> s1 >> s2;
    int a[26] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++)
        a[s1[i]-'a']++;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++)
        a[s2[i]-'a']--;
    long long int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        ans += abs(a[i]);
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: [ASCII_Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)
This will help you better understand what the other answers are referencing/based on.

Comment: This code is missing a comment like the input must be lowercase [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) letters. And, it should be run with the input using the same character encoding (or compabile) the compiler used for the execution character encoding. ([-fexec-charset](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) or [/execution-charset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=vs-2017)). [If these encodings are all ASCII-compatible, it just works. So, people say ASCII even when it's not.]

Answer (score 4):

It means that somebody is making assumptions. You can do that with characters that represent an integer: `c - '0'` will give you the integer value corresponding to the character `'0'`, `'1'`, '`2`', ... '`9`'. That's guaranteed by the language definition. There no such guarantee for any other character values. So this code is **guessing** that `c - 'a'` will produce a numeric value that somehow reflects the character that `c` represents. In the most common character encodings it works; in ASCII, which is by far the most widely used, if `c` represents a lower-case letter, then `c - 'a'` maps `'a'` to 0, `'b'` to 1, ..., `'z'` to 25. But there are character representations for which that is not true.

Note, however, that this code does not do any input validation. If someone typed a 'Z', a '0', or a ';' (to name just a few), the resulting index would be outside the array bounds, and bad things would probably happen.

As to `int a[26] = {0};`, that's called **aggregate initialization**. An array is an aggregate, that is, it hold multiple values. An initializer of the form `{something}` copies `something` to the first element in the aggregate, and sets the rest of the elements to 0. So `int a[26] = {0};` sets all 26 elements of the array `a` to 0.

The initializer in aggregate initialization does not have to have the value 0. `int a[26] = {3};` would set the first element (`a[0]`) to 3, and the rest of the elements of the array to 0.

Aggregate initialization is not restricted to a single value. You can have as many values as you want, separated by commas. So `int a[26] = { 1, 2, 3 };` would set the first three elements to 1, 2, and 3, respectively, and all the rest to 0. And if there are more initializers than there are elements, the extra ones are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the expression (with `c` being `char`)

```
c - 'a'
```

is used to take a character in the range [`'a'`, `'z'`] (which is of size `26`, due to its roots on the English alphabet) and compute an index for the letter (e.g. `'a'` being `0`, `'b'` being `1`, etc.).

---

Similarly, when you see:

```
c - '0'
```

It is typically used to compute the "numeric" value of a character in the range [`0`, `9`], e.g. `'5'` (character) is mapped to `5` (integer).

Comment: Thnq for the answer.Cleared by doubt!!

Comment: There's a critical difference between those two examples. The language definition requires the second one to work, but it does not require the first one to work. There are character encodings for which the first one does not work.

Comment: @PeteBecker Good point, thanks Pete! [lex.charset]p3, no? For most environments in 2018, and specially for a beginner, it is fine to say that it just works, though. Out of curiosity, do you know of any system still in use that doesn't use the one of the most common ones (ASCII, 8859, Unicode...) by default? Even worse, a system using one where `c - 'a'` wouldn't work?

Comment: IBM mainframes use [EBCDIC](http://www.astrodigital.org/digital/ebcdic.html). Note the gaps in the values that correspond to letters.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't agree with telling beginners "this will work" because it works on almost all systems. That leads to `if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z')`, when there's a portable solution: `if (islower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)))`. Granted, converting a letter to an index is harder, but it should only be done with awareness that it's not portable.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, EBCDIC is probably still used in compatibility systems.

Comment: @PeteBecker It depends on who you are training. If you are teaching good programmers and you have enough time, yes. However, when you are training lots of average developers on budget time, things aren't the same :)

Answer (score 1):

1) `a` is an array with 26 entries, one for each letter of the alphabet. But the character `'a'` has a value different from 0, so to get the nth letter of the array, you do `s1[i]-'a'`.

2) `int a[26] = {0}` puts a zero in the first element of the array and then default initializes the rest (meaning also zeros for ints, so be aware that it doesn't do what you think it does), and I'd say use `std::vector<int> a(26, 0);` instead. You can still use `int a[26] = {}` to initialize it with `0`s and make it clear that you understand that {0} would only initialize to this value the first element of the array and not the full array: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Of course, this program only work if only lower case letters are input. If anything else is entered, then the program's behavior is undefined and it will probably crash.

Comment: You can also use `std::array<int, 16>` and then use `fill` to initialize it to 0.

Comment: Indeed, was not clear enough. Added explanation also about the default init.

Comment: No. It's still wrong. Both forms zero initialize the whole array.

Comment: That's what I said. Did you read my edit? First initializes with 0 then does a default init for the other ints (which is 0 for ints), but I added a warning to indicate that {0} doesn't initialize the whole array with 0 because there is a zero {} but because it's default construction to 0. Putting {1} would not fill the array with 1s.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[26] = {0};
```

it's just initialization of all items in array named 'a' with zeroes.
When initializing array of built-in types with brace-initialization syntax, two types of initialization may take place. If there are less initializers, than the array size, then first N elements are initialized with corresponding values, and rest elements are initialized using default constructor. For built-in types default constructors do zero-initialization.

```
a[s1[i] - 'a']
```

Internally chars are simple decimal numbers. Each char has unique code associated with it. (See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)
If array "s1" holds lowercase latin symbols then `s[i]` takes symbol at position "i". Then we subtract code of symbol 'a' from code of symbol `s1[i]`, getting alphabetical number of symbol `s1[i]` (counting from zero). Ex: `'a'-'a' = 0`, `'b' - 'a' = 1`
Then we use calculated 'number' to access element in array "a" at position 'number'

Comment: ASCII is very common but not a guaranteed encoding. The code in the OP only requires an encoding where the lower case letters are encoded sequentially.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, yes you're correct. But most commonly used encodings maps latin chars to exactly same codes as in ascii

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher, take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization. The syntax loks misleading, but does the thing.

Comment: Sorry, removed my comment, it was wrong. Still your explanation is not clear about where the `0`s come from.

Answer (score 0):

in `a[s1[i] - 'a']` value of `s1[i]` minus the ascii value of 'a' will be the index of `a[]`. make sure that `s1[i]` is greater than ascii value of character.

and about the below , first element will be set 0

```
    int a[26] = {0};
```